# Creating and downloading a text file on a Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, text

I've built a visualforce page that has a button that creates and stores a text file as an attachment on a custom object. I'd like for this text file to be available as a download link on the visualforce page, but am having issues creating this download link.

Has anyone done this before? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You just need to query the attachment record or otherwise obtain its ID, then construct a link to it:

```
<a  download="{!AttachmentName}" 
    href="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, AttachmentId)}">
    Download
</a>
```

You may need to make some adjustments to this, but it should work without too much modification.